# How to draw image on the right side of the UITableView cell on iOS 7 on iPad?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios7

How to draw image on the right side of the UITableView cell on iOS 7 on iPad?

Tried and don't help the following code:

1. `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`
2. `[cell contentView].frame = CGRectMake(0, [cell contentView].frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, [cell contentView].frame.size.height);`

Comment: Have you tried using the `accessoryView` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely want to set the `accessoryView` property on `UITableViewCell`. This will put a an image view on the right side of a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        // Configure cell
    }

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"<some image name>.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = image;
}
```

Comment: Then I don't see images at all. How to show accessoryView? Or remove it and extend contentView to the right border of the table?

Comment: `cell.accessoryView = image` helps, thanks! But images are not centered on the vertical axis.

Comment: I think the vertical alignment will be affected the size and shape of your image.